# "System Cannot Find the Path Specified." Error in Executing Antlr4 Program Using Antlr 4 Code Generator in Command Line

Tags: c#, antlr4, nuget-package

I'm following [this tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/language-server-dot-visual-studio/) and it asks to download the Antlr 4 Code Generator which I downloaded from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.CodeGenerator/) and decompressed it.
According to the tutorial, I should then execute the following command:

```
/tools/antlr4-csharp-4.6.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar -package <NAMESPACE-OF-YOUR-PROGRAM> -o <OUTPUT_DIR> -Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_5 <PATH-TO-GRAMMAR>
```

Accordingly, I executed the following command:

```
/tools/antlr4-csharp-4.6.6-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar -package myTest -o /output -Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_5 Hello.g4
```

I have an "output" directory in the de-compressed folder, and a Hello.g4 file in the directory itself. However, when I tried to execute this command I get the below error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

What should be the correct path specification for this?